# How can I create a drop down list in a interface for a PLC using Codesys v2. 3

Tags: visualization, plc, codesys

I'm doing an interface for a WAGO PLC and I'm using codesys v2. 3 software. But I'm needing to create a drop down list to choose some variables depending of the process I want to realize with the system. But I haven't found how to do it. Also, I have though to do a text box to type the data and then get the data from it but I should have to validate that the data is correct. More complicated.

Could you help me. Ill be granted.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I would create another window with list of elements of supposed dropdown and a buton on the main screen to call that window as dialog.